# Adding flags using argparse to provide a list of options

Tags: python

I have written this program to provide a list of options using the flag --list. So, I want to use --list to provide all the options whereas when I am using --list --ex, I just want to provide a part of the list of options.

Here is the program -

```
import argparse
import sys
options = {
    'external': {
        },
    'internal': {
        }
}


def print_list(value):
    l1 = []
    l2 = []

    for k, v in options.iteritems():
        if k == "external":
            for opt, val in options["external"].iteritems():
                l1.append(opt)
        elif k == "internal":
            for opt,val in options["internal"].iteritems():
                l2.append(opt)
    if value == "external":
        return l1

    elif value == "internal":
        return l2
    elif value == "all":
        return l1 + l2

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Testing argparse"
    )

parser.add_argument("--list", action = "store_true")
parser.add_argument("--ex", action = "store_true")
parser.add_argument("--in", action = "store_true")
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])

if args.list:
    val = print_list("all")
    for items in val:
        print items

if  not args.list and args.ex:
    parser.error("You need to provide list option")

if args.ex:
    val = print_list("external")
    for items in val:
        print items
```

So when I do, --list --ex I get all the options, plus the external options. Whereas when I type --list --ex, I just want the external options.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `--list` on the command line sets `args.list` to `True` and putting `--ex` on the command line makes `args.ex` `True` as well.  Your code checks `args.list` and sees that it's true so it prints out all options.  Then it checks `args.ex` which is also `True` so it prints out the external options.

Answer (score 0):

```
if args.list and args.external:
    val = print_list("external")
    for items in val:
        print items


elif args.list:
    val = print_list("all")
    for items in val:
        print items
```

I just made a small change in the code, and was able to achieve what I wanted, thanks.